WebView Drag and Drop functionality isn't working
I have a simple code which renders the url using webView. I have a functionality of drag and drop on the web. which works perfectly fine when I check it on an actual browser, but it is not working on .NET MAUI app. Please help.
I tried with default webView but this didn't work.
<WebView
    x:Name="contentView"
    WidthRequest="1080"
    />

public partial class ContentPreviewPage : ContentPage
{
    public ContentPreviewPage(
            string url
        )
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        contentView.Source = url;
    }

This is my web
<button draggable="true" id="1" class="option" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="1">
                        <img draggable="false" src="assets/images/opt1.png">
                        <button draggable="true" id="2" class="option" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" value="2">
                        <img draggable="false"  src="assets/images/opt2.png">

and this is related js
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("value", ev.target.value);
}

function drop(ev, dropableValue, dropid) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    attempts = parseInt($('#attempts').text());
    correctans = parseInt($('#correctans').text());
    if (attempts != 0) {
        attempts--;
        $('#attempts').text(attempts);
    var value = ev.dataTransfer.getData("value");
    if ($('#' + data).val()== dropableValue) {
        showAlert(1);
        document.getElementById(dropid).appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
      
              correctans++;
        $('#correctans').text(correctans + '/' + totalquestion);
        if(attempts == 0)
        {
            $('.optionDiv :input').attr('disabled', true);
        
        var percentage = (correctans/totalquestion)*100;
        completedAlert(attempts, correctans, percentage.toFixed(2));
    }
        $("#" + data).removeClass("answerclass");
        $('#' + dropid).removeProp("ondragover");
        $('#' + data).removeProp("draggable");
        count += 1;
  
        if (count == 10) {
            $('input').attr('disabled', true);
            var percentage = (correctans / totalquestion) * 100;
            completedAlert(attempts, correctans, percentage.toFixed(2));
        }
    }
    else {
        showAlert(2);
        if(attempts == 0)
        {
            $('.optionDiv :input').attr('disabled', true);
        
        var percentage = (correctans/totalquestion)*100;
        completedAlert(attempts, correctans, percentage.toFixed(2));
    }
    }
}
else {
    $('input').attr('disabled', true);
    var percentage = (correctans / totalquestion) * 100;
    completedAlert(attempts, correctans, percentage.toFixed(2));
}
}


Is there any relevant log on this problem?

there isn't much
(CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.10\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (12856) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (14292) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

How can we reproduce this problem on our side? Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?
